# Create multiple components to be accessed later (change their height for instance) in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have rather architectural/design problem which I'm currently trying to address with react. I want to create one wrapping div (parent) and multiple div children with certain heights initially assigned. Later on, I want to change their heights when certain event occurs (say, on of these child divs was clicked). I know it might be super easy to solve in react, but since I started just recently I'm trying to come up with the best (react-like) way possible. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the Component state, simply set an initial state with the width and height. Something like

```
state = { width:100, height:100}
```

then set this properties on your div like this:

```
<div style={{width:this.state.width, height:this.state.height}}>
   [content here]
</div>
```

Finally update your state on your onClick event

```
 onClick={()=>this.setState({width:newWidth, height:newHeight})}
```